# Rather than sending in numbers, having code passed to an individual in genetic programming? ECJ

Tags: java, genetic-programming, evolutionary-algorithm

I'm using ECJ with Java.  I have an army of individuals who I all want to have the same brain.

Basically, I'd like to evolve the brains using GP.  I want things like "`if-on-enemy-territory`" and "`if-sense-target`" for if statements and "`go-home`" or "`move-randomly`" or "`shoot`" for terminals.

However, these statements need to be full executable Java code.  How can I do this with ECJ?

*FOR EXAMPLE:*

I wish to have a terminal named "`moveRandom`".  If I were to code this within my soldier class, it would look like:

```
private void moveRandomly(SoldierWorld world)
 {
  //..snip.

  int newX = (int)(this.getLocation().x + speed * Math.cos(this.getDirection() * Math.PI / 180.0));
  int newY = (int)(this.getLocation().y - speed * Math.sin(this.getDirection() * Math.PI / 180.0));

  Point newPoint = new Point(newX, newY);
  this.setLocation(newPoint); 
 }
```

Now how can I make a terminal that will perform this code?

Answer (score 1):

I would enumerate all the functions that you have and then make a function set class that executes a function associated with the enum:

```
public class FunctionSet
{
    public enum FuncName
    {
        MOVE_RANDOM,
        SHOOT,
        GO_HOME,
        ...
    }

    public FunctionSet()
    {

    }

    public void Execute(FuncName funcName, Soldier soldier, SoldierWorld world)
    {
        switch(funcName)
        {
            case FuncName.MOVE_RANDOM:
                soldier.moveRandom(world);
                break;
            case FuncName.SHOOT:
                soldier.shoot(...);
                break;
            case FuncName.GO_HOME:
                soldier.goHome(...);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

So the nodes in your expression tree are not going to contain an actual function now, but only `FuncName` enums... you might have to do some extra work, like keep track of how many parameters are associated with each function and place that in a hash map.

Alternately you can use reflection to get all the applicable function names from the `Soldier` class and then place them in a map with the corresponding number of parameters.